# share core data iPhone macbook

Tags: ios, database, macos, synchronization, watchos-2

I want to make a time management app for iOs, OsX and apple watch. Synching database between apple watch and iOs is possible with core data, I haven't tried but [WKInterfaceController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceController/openParentApplication:reply:) seems like solves this problem. But is it possible to make an application for sync data between iOS and OsX?

Thank you,
Have a nice day.